# Rails - How to translate form_for collection_select to simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I translate the following `form_for` -  `collection_select` to simple_form?

`<%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, @service_menus, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>`

To...

`<%= f.input ...`

> **Update requested:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
    <div class="field">

        <!--Working - selected value saves to db-->
        <%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, ServiceMenu.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>

        <!--Selected value does not save to db-->
        <%#= f.input :service_menu, :collection => @service_menus, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, :include_blank => false, prompt: "Select a main service" %>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for :styles do |task| %>
            <%= render 'style_fields', :f => task %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add New Style', f, :styles, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div><br>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

---

**controller**

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_service, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
      @services = current_tech.services
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @service = current_tech.services.build
    @service_menus = ServiceMenu.all
  end

  def create
    @service = current_tech.services.build(service_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @service_menus = ServiceMenu.all
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.update(service_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @service.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to services_url, notice: 'Service was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_service
      @service = Service.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:name, :service_menu_id, styles_attributes: [:id, :tech_id, :name, :hours, :minutes, :price, :details, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Comment: If you can wrap it as ***form object*** (i.e., `f.collection_select`) then this will work `<%= f.input :service_menu, :collection => @service_menus, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => true %>`

Comment: Read this section https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: Try this `<%= f.input :service_menu, :collection => @service_menus, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :selected => @service.service_menu_id :include_blank => true %>`

Comment: You are awesome, thanks! Please add your comment to an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap it as ***form object*** (i.e., `f.collection_select`) then this will work

```
<%= f.input :service_menu, :collection => @service_menus, :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :selected => @service.service_menu_id :include_blank => true %>
```

Comment: Hi @Pavan, thank you for your reply. The menu does not retain the value of the `service_menu` name.

Comment: @captainawesome I didn't get you.

Comment: The old code `<%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, @service_menus, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>` retained the `name` of the `service` in the menu whenever I attempt to edit. Now if I were to edit the menu, the value will go to the first selection. if I were to save a menu to say `Brakes`, if I were to go back and edit that menu, it would not say `Brakes` but rather the first selection in the menu. Hopefully I'm making sense. :(

Comment: @captainawesome Can you update the question with the form code?

Comment: I was wondering why the menu was not retaining the value after attempting to update the `menu`. The value I select from the `menu` is not being saved to the db. The code you provided is not saving to the db.

Comment: @captainawesome It depends on how you are accessing it in the controller. If you can update the full form code and controller, I can able to help you.

Comment: I've updated the post above. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Forgot to add the controller. :(